# How to write Angular/React-like PHP Components

Tags: php, angularjs, components

I wrote a PHP Class that works by constructing a paginator by passing it a current page value and a number of pages to show value like this:

```
$paginator = new Paginator(1,4);
```

then I out put it like this

```
<?php
    require_once("./partials/pagination.php");
?>
... tons of html
<?php
   $paginator = new Paginator(4,2  );
   echo($paginator->paginator)
?>
```

I'd love to be able to simplify it down to something like

```
<?php
   <Paginator pageNum='1' numToShow='3' />
?>
```

anyone have any thoughts on how this might be done? Other than writing a parser.

This project must be done in PHP for a variety of reasons or I would use react/angular. If anyone has any tips on how to write a "Componentized" php front end, i'd love to hear.
(Needs to be served statically, so I cannot use JS for this)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just separate logic of instanciating paginator and view layer? You'll finally get just this:

```
<?= $paginator->paginate(2,4); ?>
```

Comment: So for example, have a controller that instantiates all my classes as need, then load them into the view similar to you you do above? for that couldn't I do something like require("controller");
then do controller.init();
then 
echo(controller.header)
echo(controller.content)
echo(controller.paginator)
echo(controller.footer)

still new to php coming from a javascript based front end background so any help is appreciated